# SLAM Goal Babbling

Tags: localization, slam, motion-planning, mapping

I am struggling to find good links to the use of [goal babbling](http://matthias-rolf.blogspot.com/p/goal-babbling.html?m=1) in SLAM applications. Has this technique been used as a method for optimizing movement in a SLAM environment?

Comment: @Spiked3 sorry, new to edit editing. Accepted Paul's beneficial link, but your edit contained some grammatical errors at the end of the sentence so I rejected for now.

Comment: No prob. His edit has some errors on the link formatting (that looks like it was fixed), and links go stale so I tried to add some context.

Comment: @Spike3 please feel free to reinsert your edit giving context, as I have not seen this subject mentioned on the Robotics beta before.